# One of my media queries is not responding

Tags: javascript, css, html

everything works fine with the first and third media query

but when my screen is in the middle one:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 600px)
```

it doesn't work .

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  // some css styles //

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  // some css styles //

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  // some css styles //

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>New Responsive design web page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheetTest.css" type="text/css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale = 1.0" />
</head>
```

Comment: How does it NOT work? How wide is your screen when it fails?

Comment: it doesn't work when it is between 481px and 600 px .

Comment: it seems to be working fine: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL2LwLgy/) Can you explain in more detail what's wrong? Or maybe try and recreate the issue in a fiddle

Comment: Are you sure your screen width is between 481px and 600px when it fails? Can you create a fiddle that other people could recreate your issue? If nobody besides you could reproduce it, then no one could help.

Comment: Yes , I will create a fiddle and post it. Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `}` at the end of your second media query (right after the `.Finish` selector).

Once removed it works as expected: [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zv2m97dw/2/)